# Eliminar archivo en python

Tags: python

Estoy trabajando con python en una RaspberryPi.
Tengo que eliminar todos los archivos .flac que esten en el directorio, en mi caso es

> /home/volumio/flac_in/45688.flac

hago

> os.remove("/home/volumio/flac_in/45688.flac")

y obtengo error de sintaxis.
No hay modo que funcione, me pueden ayudar.
Muchas gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido @danielfelix a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: No veo cómo esa línea puede darte error de sintaxis, a menos que se trate de un problema de indentación, o de algún paréntesis sin cerrar en la línea anterior, etc. Habría que ver el código en contexto. Otra cosa sería que no te encuentre el fichero que quieres borrar, pero eso no sería un error de sintaxis.

Comment: Mas adelante conté q estaba mal planteada la pregunta, gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Creo entender que la implementación en `RaspberryPi` generan archivos con una extensión `.flac`  en el directorio `"/home/volumio/flac_in/` y por ende no se puede saber de antemano el nombre que tendrán dichos archivos.

Al respecto se puede importar [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) a efecto de saber que archivos con determinada extensión se encuentran en un directorio específico a fin de eliminarlos ya sea con `os.remove` o también con `os.unlink`.

En el caso que se consulta sería el siguiente:

```
import os, glob

archivos_borrados = [] # a efecto de tener un reporte de qué se ha borrado

# se buscan todos los archivos ".flac" en el directorio objetivo
for archivo_flac in glob.glob('/home/volumio/flac_in/*.flac'): 
    archivosBorrados.append(archivo_flac) # opcional, es  para saber que se borrar
    os.unlink(archivo_flac)               # sólo se elimina una vez sino aparecerá error
    #os.remove(archivo_flac)              # también es válido

if archivosBorrados != []:
    print(archivosBorrados)
else:
    print('Ningun Archivo Flac Borrado')
```

También es recomendable usar `os.path.isfile("/home/volumio/flac_in/miArchivo.flac")`en un condicional `if` para verificar si `miArchivo.flac` existe, de lo contrario se obtendrá error.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from shutil import rmtree
rmtree("carpeta")
```

hola, en tu caso si es una carpeta se tiene que usar este. O si solo es un archivo es el que tu dice, lo que hay que ver es que si el file desde donde estas escribiendo las lineas estan en la misma carpeta..

Comment: Muchas gracias! en realidad estaba mal planteada la consulta, lo que quiero es eliminar un archivo del que no sé el nombre, intenté con *.flac y sus variantes y no logré hacerlo.